# Distributing Game, written in c++

Tags: c++

I have written a game using: OpenGL, GLEW, GLFW, glm, 
It is written in c++.

I wanted to send it to a friend to play, it can run on any system, but the systems I have tested it on are able to use the Makefile and compile it properly as they are set up correctly.

But my friend does not have the correct set-up, and doesn't even have g++ installed.

How do I package the game so that I can simply send them the file, with an executable which allows them to run it without any issues.

What would they need to install to make it run (if they do) and what do I need to change in the files or what do I need to include in order to send him the game.

Comment: [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/291rth/how_to_deploy_a_game_on_linux/) may help.

Comment: If you compile it statically, it'll include all dependencies, and be entirely self-contained. At the same time, the file will be very large, as it won't be dynamically linking anything at runtime. Google for `g++ static linking` If you'd rather not go that route, and want to link dynamic, then you need to write an installer. In it, you'll need to deliver all of your dependency libraries, dynamically compiled executables, assets, etc.

Comment: Which OS do you target ?

Comment: Normally, after you compile it, they should be able to run it, as long as you include all the required items, such as data files (art) and any DLLs. You can drop it into an empty folder, zip it up and place it somewhere like in a Dropbox location or a shared Google Drive folder.